# Select/ Updated last inputted sql row

Tags: sql, sqlite

I feel like this is a very easy problem, but I have been trying to figure this out for many hours with sqlite3.

All I need is to retrieve the last row of data input into the table and update it with a value.

I've tried `c.execute("select max(timestamp) from sensor_data")` and it will only return the most recent timestamp.

The code below is my table name and columns.

`sensor_data(ph, air_temp, water_temp, humidity, water_level, timestamp)`

Answer (score 2):

You need to `SELECT` the row that has the maximum `timestamp`, which you can do with this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM sensor_data
WHERE timestamp = (SELECT MAX(timestamp) FROM sensor_data)
```

Or more simply

```
SELECT *
FROM sensor_data
ORDER BY timestamp DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

To update this row, use something like

```
UPDATE sensor_data
SET air_temp = 20
WHERE timestamp = (SELECT MAX(timestamp) FROM sensor_data)
```

Comment: Or `SELECT * FROM demo order by id desc limit 1;`, but the main idea was hit already.

Comment: @domino indeed; I've added that possibility to the answer, although it doesn't save much for an `UPDATE` query since that needs a subquery regardless and if the table is properly indexed one should be as fast as the other.

Comment: hmm, when i try "c.execute("select * from sensor_data where timestamp = (select max(timestamp) from sensor_data")" to select and c.execute("UPDATE sensor_data SET water_temp = 20 WHERE timestamp = (SELECT MAX(timestamp) FROM sensor_data") to update i keep getting an incomplete input error?

Comment: @MikeSandstrom you're missing the closing parentheses for the subqueries it should be: `c.execute("select * from sensor_data where timestamp = (select max(timestamp) from sensor_data)")` and `c.execute("UPDATE sensor_data SET water_temp = 20 WHERE timestamp = (SELECT MAX(timestamp) FROM sensor_data)")`

Comment: @Nick beautiful, thank you nick. I am new to sql, thanks for this. I promised myself I'd finish this before bedtime so you helped me get some sleep!

Answer (score 0):

You could use:Referred from documentation
https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#last_insert_rowid

```
SELECT last_insert_rowid()
```

Comment: this is everything in my table "[(None, None, 8.05, None, None, None), (8.05, 71.6, None, 45.3, 337, '2020-01-24 16:07:43')]".  when i run your suggestion ""c.execute('select last_insert_rowid()')"" i receive ""[(0,)]"" as output. I need the entire row.